# Proving function is optimal

Tags: calculus

I have two functions that represent an amount of bits. I want to know how I can show that if I pick, $$b = (\log _{2} (n))^2$$ then the total bits that these two functions represent are minimized - That no other choice of b can get the number of bits quite as small.

This question comes from this statement from [this Stack Overflow 2-part answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72580833/1718122):

> Surprisingly, the optimal choice of b turns out to be b = log2 n (that is, b = (log n)2).

The two functions are:

$$\frac{n \cdot \log_{2}(n)}{b}$$

and

$$\frac{n \cdot \log_{2}(b)}{\log_{2}(n)}$$

[image: graph]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two functions together represent a quantity of bits. You can find the point at which they are both minimized by taking the derivative and setting it equal to zero. *Why set it to zero?* Because the slope of the horizontal tangent line is equal to `0` when these functions are at their minimum and maximum values - eg. "Critial Points" - and that's what we're interested in finding.

$$
\frac{d}{db} \left[\frac{n \log_2{n}}{b} + \frac{n \log_2{b}}{\log_2{n}}\right] = 0
$$

$$
\frac{-n \log_2{n}}{b^2} + \frac{n}{b\log_2{n}} = 0
$$

$$
\frac{n}{b\log_2{n}} = \frac{n \log_2{n}}{b^2}
$$

$$
\frac{1}{b\log_2{n}} = \frac{\log_2{n}}{b^2}
$$

$$
\frac{b}{\log_2{n}} = \log_2{n}
$$

$$
b = (\log_2{n})^2
$$